# how to change TTL of hbase table from phoenix

Tags: hbase, apache-phoenix

I am able to give **TTL** of an HBase table at table creation time. How to change the TTL of the table after creation. Is it possible to change the **TTL** at runtime with out disabling the table?
Thanks in advance :)

Using Hortonworks 2.6 HDP
Phoenix Version 4.7 
HBase Version   1.2.1

Comment: having the same question. did you find an answer?

Comment: HI Janar..For changing it in run time i did't got any solution. You can check whether any new improvements is there in latest  apache phoenix 4.14

Answer (score 1):

```
ALTER TABLE <table_name> SET TTL=<value in secs>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can execute `create if not exists` DDL again with a different TTL value. For example:

```
create table if not exists TEST_TABLE (...) TTL=86400
```

Or remove TTL:

```
create table if not exists TEST_TABLE (...) TTL=NULL
```